# [c# WinForm]Add text to listbox from another form with dynamically created buttons

Tags: c#, forms, listbox

I have this forms:

**MainKozep:**

- Contains tableLayoutPanel witch contains:

  - Panel - named "panel1" (loaded with Tab(*) Form)
  - Listbox - named "tetels"
  - Listbox - named "tetels_ar"
- Buttons wich load Tab1-Tab10 to panel1

**Tab1:**

There are dynamically created buttons (from database), and every buttons is clickable (with button.Click += delegate{})

I tried a lot of solutions but didn't worked, so my problem is:

When one of the buttons clicked in Tab(*), this need to write the exact variable to tetels Listbox and write another variable to tetels_ar Listbox.

Thanks for your help,
Dris

Answer (score 0):

if tetels and tetels_ar are dynamically created, instantiate them with class scope. Then, from your buttonClick handler, run buttonClicked as below. Here, I'm updating tetels with a string, but you would set that value to whatever variable you want:

```
ListBox tetels = new ListBox();
    ListBox tetels_AR = new ListBox();
    private void buttonClicked(string buttonName)
    {
        tetels.Items.Add(buttonName);
        tetels_AR.Items.Add("otherValue" + buttonName);
    }
```

If you use a lot of different listviews, you can add dynamically using the code below. Assign my_Button_Clicked as the onClick event for each of your dynamically created buttons, then:

```
private void buttonClicked(string listName, string variableValue)
    {
        ListBox l = (ListBox)Controls.Find(listName, true)[0];
        l.Items.Add(variableValue);

    }
    private void myButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        buttonClicked("tutels", b.Name);
        buttonClicked("tutels_AR", b.Text);

    }
```

create your buttons as such:

```
private void createButton(string name, string buttonText,string parentControlName)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Name = name;
        b.Text = buttonText;
        b.Click += myButton_Clicked;
        Control c = Controls.Find(parentControlName, true)[0];
        c.Controls.Add(b);

    }
```

Comment: tetels and tetels_ar static, the buttons are dynamically created.
Example:
If i click on of the buttons on Form2, this should write a string to Listbox(named tetels) - witch is on Form1